# Please help me identify the characters on the seal (Characters identified: 知惠子)

Tags: seal

Please help me identify the characters of the seal (again).
My friend identified one of the characters as ’和’ but she's not sure with it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The characters are **知惠子**, which point to a Japanese name probably pronounced as *Chieko* (**ちえこ**).

<sub>You should visit the chat rooms in japanese.stackexchange.com to confirm this.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much!